# Finding and counting duplicate filenames

Tags: linux, shell

Need to search through all sub folders of current folder recursively and list all files of certain type and number of duplicates

e.g. if current folder is home and there are 2 sub folders dir1 and dir2
Then i need it to search dir1 and dir2 and list file names and number of duplicates

this is what i have so far:
I am using

```
find -name "*.h" .
```

to get a list of all the files of certain type.
I need to now count duplicates and create a new list like

```
 file1.h 2

 file2.h 1
```

where file1 is file name and 2 is number of duplicates overall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use `uniq --count`

You can use a set of core utilities to do this quickly. For example, given the following setup:

```
mkdir -p foo/{bar,baz}
touch foo/bar/file{1,2}.h
touch foo/baz/file{2,3}.h
```

you can then find (and count) the files with a pipeline like this:

```
find foo -name \*.h -print0 | xargs -0n1 basename | sort | uniq -c
```

This results in the following output:

```
    1 file1.h
    2 file2.h
    1 file3.h
```

If you want other output formats, or to order the list in some other way than alphabetically by file, you can extend the pipeline with another sort (e.g. `sort -nr`) or reformat your columns with sed, awk, perl, ruby, or your text-munging language of choice.

Comment: Slight simplification: "find -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq -c"

Comment: An ugly hack that mostly works:`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0n1 basename | sort | uniq -c | grep -v ' 1 '`

Answer (score 4):

```
find -name "*.h"|awk -F"/" '{a[$NF]++}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]>1)print i,a[i]}'
```

*Note: This will print files with similar names and only if there are more than one.*

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. If someone wants to find duplicates, and isn't doing it by eyeball, then there must be many files to look at. If there are many files to look at, then it makes sense to only return the files that you are looking for instead of a screen with many counts that may mostly be counts of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shell script,  the following code will print a filename of there are duplicates, then below that list all duplicates.

The script is used as in the following exanmple:

```
./find_duplicate.sh ./ Project
```

and will search the current directory tree for file names with 'project' in it.

```
#! /bin/sh

find "${1}" -iname *"${2}"* -printf "%f\n" \
    | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' \
    | sort -n \
    | uniq -c \
    | sort -n -r \
    | while read LINE
      do
        COUNT=$( echo ${LINE} | awk '{print $1}' )
        [ ${COUNT} -eq 1 ] && break
        FILE=$( echo ${LINE} | cut -d ' ' -f 2-10000 2> /dev/null )
        echo "count: ${COUNT} | file: ${FILE}"
        FILE=$( echo ${FILE} | sed -e s/'\['/'\\\['/g -e s/'\]'/'\\\]'/g )
        find ${1} -iname "${FILE}" -exec echo "  {}" ';'
        echo
      done
```

if you wish to search for all files (and not search for a pattern in the name, replace the line:

```
find "${1}" -iname *"${2}"* -printf "%f\n" \
```

with

```
find "${1}" -type f -printf "%f\n" \
```